# Как извлечь 2 бита из слова, сделать между ними and, or и т.д. и результаты как биты поместить в переменную?

Tags: ассемблер

Как из слова (16 бит) вытащить 2 конкретных бита, провести над ними 16 логических операций типа and, or, затем каждый результат как бит положить в слово 16 бит?
Задача была такой: "Реализуйте логическую арифметику, при которой в одном слове хранилось бы 16 логических переменных."

Код на С++ с ассемблерной вставкой ниже, хотя там и не особо что есть.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    unsigned short int number;
    short int b1, b2, result;


    cout << "Введите число от 0 до 65535: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Введите индекс бита от 0 до 15" << endl;
    cin >> b1;
    cout << "Введите индекс бита от 0 до 15" << endl;
    cin >> b2;

    __asm {

        mov ax, number

    }



    cout << result << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Так а что не получается?

Comment: Я же написал в вопросе.

Comment: Вот и непонятно - если человеку знакомы слова and и or, то в чём затруднения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну давайте начнём с такого:

```
mov cx, b1
mov dx, ax
shr dx, cl
and dx, 1
```

теперь в младшем бите dx лежит b1-й бит ax

А так

```
mov dx, 1
shl dx, cl
and dx, ax
```

в b1-ом бите dx хранится копия соответствующего бита ax